# How to filter by relationships using each Prisma orm

Tags: orm, prisma

I have a one to many relationship, and I need to filter the relationship values, I need to bring all the records that contain all the values ​​of the array/

example: `const attributes = ["Car", "Bike", "Truck"]`

```
prisma.car.findMany({
  where: {
    attribute: {
      typeCar: {
        every: {
          value: { hasSome: attributes },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This search works only if all `attributes` exist, if any attribute does not exist, nothing is returned

I need it to return the record, even if typeCar does not contain all records.

How could I do that with the prisma?

My model

```
model Car {
  id           String     @id
  name         String
  status       String
  description  String
  thumbnailUrl String?
  groupId      String?
  categoryName String
  attribute    Attribute[]
  images       CarImage[]
  createdAt    DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime?  @updatedAt

  @@map("car")
}

model Attribute {
  id            String     @id
  typeCar       String[]
  car           Car?   @relation(fields: [carId], references: [id])
  carId         String?
  createdAt     DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime?  @updatedAt

  @@map("attributeProductValue")
}
```

Comment: Have tried using the `some` operator as seen in the [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/composite-types#filtering-for-many-composite-types:~:text=some%3A%20One%20or%20more%20of%20the%20items%20in%20the%20list%20must%20match%20the%20condition)

Comment: Yes, but `some` returns if there are one or more values, I need it to return whenever there are exactly the values ​​I pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found was to add a new field in the `car` table. Saving the values ​​of the `typeCar`

```
model Car {
  id            String     @id
  name          String
  status        String
  description   String
  thumbnailUrl  String?
  groupId       String?
  categoryName  String
  attribute     Attribute[]
  images        CarImage[]
  typeCarValues String[]
  createdAt     DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime?  @updatedAt

  @@map("car")
}
```

So I can filter without going through the relationship, and the `hasEvery` option works.

example: `const attributes = ["Car", "Bike", "Truck"]`

```
prisma.car.findMany({
  where: {
    typeCarValues: {
      hasEvery: attributes,
    },
  },
})
```

The problem was in filtering the relationship in attributes using `every` and then `hasEvery`, to return the value all `attributes` of `typeCar` need to be informed and exist, if any of them is not informed, it does not return.